# Authorize resource (eg. image) access through a field in mongodb vs authorization token?

Tags: mongodb, security, oauth, authorization

I have a question related to private resource access.

I am designing an application where each user can upload files (eg. images, videos, pdf etc.) in their personal space. So, when I receive a request for a certain resource, I need to check whether a certain file should be accessible to the user who has sent that request.

The way I intend to allow access is the following :-

1. Browser sends a request for, say, a user's private image, along with user's jwt (access token created on user login).
2. If the request is not accompanied a jwt, server sends a 401 response.
3. However, if the request is accompanied by a jwt, user name is retrieved from the jwt.
4. Also, requested url contains the file id, this id is used to retrieve a mongo doc corresponding to the resource (in this case an image).
5. Mongo doc contains a field - accessibleTo: ["user_name1", "user_name2", ...].
6. User name of user who is trying to access the file is checked against this array (accessibleTo) in mongodb.
7. If user name exists in the array, the resource (in this case the image) is sent to the browser, if not, server send a 401 response.

My question is that I have read at places that authorization must be allowed via tokens, however, a simple db check seems to work fine for my application. Am I missing something? Could you please explain the cons of this implementation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your described design includes token-based authentication via session token:

> along with user's jwt access token (created on user login)

which you then use to check the access permissions on the server side.

This provides image security, assuming you have sufficiently short session expiration. Using session has pros and cons in comparison to other methods, but from security point of view is [sufficiently good](https://www.twelve21.io/how-to-access-images-securely-with-oauth-2-0/) for images. Notice that one of the disadvantages mentioned in [the same article](https://www.twelve21.io/how-to-access-images-securely-with-oauth-2-0/) is that using sessions in general can expose your site to [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), but if you do plan to use the sessions, this disadvantage is not image specific.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's okay the way you are trying to do it.

Here's some scenario,

- Is `username` is `unique` in your collection?? if that's not the case
  then you should store `accessibleTo: ["user_id1", "user_id2", ...]`
  and at the same time you should include your `user_id` in jwt
  palyload.
- How are you sending the resource to browser, if the user has access to it according to your design?? If the resource is stored somewhere and you are sending the direct url of that resource, next time user can access the resource directly without hitting your endpoint. So if you need control over that, then you need to add some sort of authorization in your storage server resources link. Here's how to do it on aws s3 - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html